# Background rect of d3's brush control not taking the whole area of svg

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to use d3's [brush control](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#brush). All works good except the `rect.background` of the brush is not expanding to fill the whole SVG, thus not allowing me to use the brush on the most right and bottom areas of SVG (which are not covered with background).

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Y6h9/2/) illustrates the problem (scroll to the right and try using brush there) I've outlined the .background rect with the border.

What is the reason of this? And how to make the brush control to work all over the SVG?

Comment: I can brush right up to the edge of the frame in your fiddle.

Comment: It's the frame of rect.background, not svg. SVG is bigger.

Comment: The SVG is exactly the size of the frame here.

Comment: what do you mean by 'frame'? (I was talking of the black border)

Comment: black border is border of rect.background. The problem is that brush works only within this area. I want it to work all over the SVG (which is **bigger**)

Comment: For me on Chrome the SVG is exactly the same size as the `rect` and the black border.

Comment: in all browsers on my machine size of SVG is 960x600, and for .background - 720x560. How can it be of same size on your computer?

Comment: Wait, you are limiting the extent of the brush explicitly through the scales that you attach to it. I see what you mean now -- if you allow the scales to extend all the way to the end of the SVG, you can brush along all of it.

Comment: Thank you! Now this error looks so obvious to me. Needed another pair of eyes though) Thanks a lot